# cmake / c++ : which package contains `-lOpenGLSupport`

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, cmake, bulletphysics

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenGLSupport`

The above error occurs when linking.

I have [googled](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=/usr/bin/ld%3a%20cannot%20find%20-lOpenGLSupport), to [no avail](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=/usr/bin/ld%3a%20cannot%20find%20-lOpenGLSupport).
Where can I obtain this library (package / build from source)?

(If this question is more at home/ appropriate on superuser.com, mods feel free to move it)

Thanks!

---

OS is Ubuntu Karmic.

Comment: @sarnold : Using cmake. The project is not mine, and I am very certain that there is no problem with the build script, and its arguments. I am merely missing that particular library. Do you which dev package (or other means) to obtain it from?

Comment: Are you really using -lOpenGLSupport or the question is what should replace your OpenGLSupport part? Please give some more details. Which packages have you installed? Are you using GLU/GLUT in your code? You need to install at least `libgl1-mesa-dev`. Search with `aptitude search libgl` and decide about the packages. After that, the compilation is something like `gcc -o prog prog.c -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXmu -lXi -lm` or less options (depends on what your code uses).

Comment: @faif : I am really using `-lOpenGLSupport`. I do already have the atest `libgl1-mesa-dev`, so that makes no difference for my part. The code definitely makes use of GLUT. I presently have `nvidia-cg-toolkit`,

Comment: (cot'd) `libopenal-dev`, `freeglu3-dev`, `mesa-utils` and `libgl1-mesa-glx-dbg` also installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`-lOpenGLSupport` appears to be from the `bulletphysics` library.**

---

**More details:**

I had built this from source, however, had not specified that it should build shared libraries. Doing this appears to have rectified the problem.

For future reference:

Build `bulletphysics` using these commands

```
cmake  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebugInfo . -G "Unix Makefiles"
make
```

---

(answering own question)